# C, how to transfer sqlite3 database handle

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm trying to make some utils for using with sqlite databases.
For that I create sqlite3_ut.h and sqlite3_ut.c files

sqlite_ut.h

```
#ifndef sqlite3_ut_h
#define sqlite3_ut_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include "sqlite3.h"

int drop_table(sqlite3 handle);

#endif
```

sqlite_ut.c

```
int drop_table(sqlite3 handle)
{
int dropped = 0;
printf("Begin Drop\n");

sqlite3_exec(handle, "BEGIN;", NULL, NULL, NULL);
sqlite3_stmt *droptab;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(handle, "DROP TABLE mytable;", -1, &droptab, 0) != SQLITE_OK)
    printf("db error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(handle));

if(droptab)
{
    sqlite3_step(droptab);
    dropped = 1;
}
else
    printf("Error: drop_table");

sqlite3_finalize(droptab);
sqlite3_exec(handle, "COMMIT;", NULL, NULL, NULL);

printf("End Drop\n");
return dropped;
}
```

sqlite_ut.h is included in main file.

```
sqlite3 *db;

int rc = sqlite3_open("m_test.db", &db);
if (rc)...

//error here
int dropped = drop_table(db);
```

Obviously, I can't transfer handle of opened database properly to drop_table function which is of sqlite3 type.

How to do that with suggested program cofiguration?

Comment: Why not, have you tried? Do you get errors?

Comment: Hey Joe. I have situation here. Compiling c++ program with c header and c file which are shown and now I get 'undefined reference to drop_table' message. What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite3 handles are of type `sqlite3 *`, not `sqlite3`. Redefine `drop_table` as follows:

```
int drop_table(sqlite3 *handle) { … }
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this as soon will be possible :)